# Exclamation mark variable `$!`

Tags: shell, environment-variables, variable

I have been studying for my Unix exam and I often saw exclamation mark variable - `$!`
If I write `echo $!` on my Mac shell tells me something like "You have mail in…"

Is purpose of this to store whether I do or do not have any mails or is there something else?

**EDIT:** Funny coincidence happened. Exactly when I wrote `echo $!` my Shell also notified me that I have some mail. So that's why I wrote that mail part.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> $! is the PID of the most recent background command.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1898563) for other special parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The shell checks for new mail after a command finished and `$MAILCHECK` or 600 seconds have passed.

`echo $!` prints the PID of the last background process.
After that, a check for mail may happen.

Answer (score 5):

`$!` is replaced by the process identifier of the last process placed in the background in the current shell, if any. The [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) provides details of all such special parameters.

To see this in action:

```
echo $!
```

should print `0` (assuming no jobs have been backgrounded)

```
man bash &
echo $!
```

should print the process identifier of the `man` process which is in the background. The full output should look something like

```
$ man bash &
[1] 4319
[1]  + 4319 suspended (tty output)  man bash
$ echo $!
4319
```